# CPU-intensive thread wisdom

Tags: windows, multithreading, cpu

I want to run a batch say 20 CPU intensive comps (basically really long nested for loop) on a machine.

Each of these 20 jobs doesn't share data with the other 19.

If the machine has N cores, should I spin off N-1 of these jobs then?  Or N?  Or should I just launch all 20, and have Windows figure out how to schedule them?

Comment: In about 6 years a CPU will have 32 cores, and this will cease to be an issue.

Comment: .. and require power directly from the sun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple answer.  The only way to know for sure is to implement and then profile your application.

Typically, for maximum throughput, if the jobs are pure CPU, you'd want one per core.  Depending on the type of work, this would include one per hyperthread code or just one per "true physical core".  (If the work is identical for all 20 jobs, then hyperthreading often slows down the overall work...)

If the jobs have *any* non-CPU functionaltiy (such as reading a file, waiting on anything, etc), then >1 work item per core tends to be much better.  For many situations, this will improve.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if you aren't sharing data, not blocking on IO, and using lots of CPU and nothing else is running on the box (and probably a few more caveats) using all the CPU's (e.g. N threads) is probably the best idea.

The best choice is probably to make it configurable and profile it and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a thread pool of some sort, so it's (reasonably) easy to tune the number of threads without affecting the structure of the program.

Once you've done that, it's a fairly simple matter of testing to find a reasonably optimal number of threads relative to the number of processors available. Chances are that even when/if they look like this should be purely CPU bound, you'll get better efficiency with the number of threads >N, but about the only way to be sure is to test.